# How can i make a button change the text on a screen?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and Java programming and I am trying to make an app where it starts out with "Goodbye World" and a button underneath. i am trying to make it so that when you press the button "Goodbye World" changes to "Hello World". Does anyone know how you can do this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 it really messy because ive been trying out different methods such as activities but if you still want me to just say so

Comment: I have given a basic idea in my answer. You need to implement similar code as per your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea to do this would be like this

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); // change with your TextView id
text.setText("Goodbye World");
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // change with your button id
btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text.setText("Hello World");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the text of Button

```
public void on Create(Bundle saved Instance State) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    set Content View(R.layout.main);
    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){
       @override
       public void onClick(view view){
       btn.setText("Hello World");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java file will look like this:

```
`package com.example.button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText("Hello World");

        }
    });

}
```

}
`Your XML file will look like this:`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/a" />
```

`

Answer (score -1):

The answer for your question is here.

activity_main.xml:

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Goodbye World" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:text="click" />

</LinearLayout>
```

on click of button:

```
public void click(View v){
    text1.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
   text2.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
  }
```

Comment: very wrong way to do it. Why do we need two `TextView` if we can get the result from only one?

Comment: See this is my way every one will have their own way, In your case if you want again goodbye world what you will do again you will setText?
If I want i will use that textview again on button click whats wrong in that?

Comment: its not about own way. Its about right way. In my code too you can easily get the old value back. That's not an issue.

Comment: how you will get the old value back if once the another text is set to that texview? If setting visibility to gone is wrong then why android provide such feature?

Comment: Follow your own way.

Comment: Ya I will follow. I did not understand what wrong you find in that? every correct output states programmers way of thinking. #Rohit5k2